# Spring boot Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/NewCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private void vNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer xCustomer)
    {
        System.out.println("Post Request");
        if(xCustomer != null 
        && xCustomer.getCustomerName() != null 
        && xCustomer.getCustomerMail() != null)
        {
            
            TableCustomerController.vGetInstance().vInsertCustomer(xCustomer);
        }
    }
```

It returns
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

How should i solve it
Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

In you method you specifically configured `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. So you limited your method and specified that consumes this typed and then you complain that it doesn't take a different type. So either remove `consumes` property or set it to `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` or to just a String `consumes = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but still it doesn't work

Comment: Well, may be MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE is the right value for the server side and instead you need to set on your client side set request header "Content-Type" to "application/json"

Comment: @MichaelGantman similar issue here if you can take a look pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77084076/type-error-application-json-in-spring-boot-3-1-controller?noredirect=1#comment135895901_77084076

Answer (score 0):

You can check if is there any exception during mapping json request.
I faced Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [...].Conflicting getter definitions for property[...]. Fix it exeption, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I don't understand. It seems you are simply saying to fix the exception. If so, then the OP is actually asking how to fix the exception. So how does your answer help him? By the way, you can use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts.