# Type Error Application/JSON in Spring Boot 3.1 controller

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am getting a type error on a POST controller when I try to send data to it. The error seems to be clear but the solution is escaping me:

**Enviroment**

Spring Boot 3.1
Java 18
MySQL8

**Entity**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bird_seq", sequenceName = "BIRD_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 50)
@Table(name = "bird")
public class Bird {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "bird_seq")
private Long id;
@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty
private String name;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Sex sex;

@OneToOne(optional = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "current_transmitter_id", nullable = true)
private Transmitter currentTransmitter;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
private List<ChickTimer> listChickTimer = new ArrayList<>();

// other fields trimmed

// single property constructor to support testing 

    public Bird(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/birds")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KiwiController {

    @Autowired
    private final BirdServiceImpl birdService;

    // tried with and without the consumes/produces
    // also tried consumes = "application/json"
    @PostMapping(value = "/testpost/", consumes = (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), produces = (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) )
    ResponseEntity<Bird> BirdCreate(@RequestBody Bird newBird) {
    Bird bird = birdService.save(newBird);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bird, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**Unsupported Media Type - Error**

```
{
"timestamp": "2023-09-11T18:29:23.830+00:00",
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:209)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\n",
"message": "Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.",
"path": "/birds/testpost/"
```

}

**Postman**

[image]
[image]

**Steps Taken So Far**

1. I have another controller on same project working fine (it doesnt even specify media type)
2. Tried with `@PostMapping(value = "/testpost/", consumes = (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), produces = (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) )` and `consumes = "application/json"`
3. Changed the controller to use another Class I have for Testing - it worked with the test Class
4. Tried to set a breakpoint on the controller on this line `Bird bird = birdService.save(newBird);` but it never gets reached
5. Tried manually addding "Accept":"application/json" to postman instead of `*/*`
6. Tried curl :

   curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/birds/testpost/ --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"bob"}'
   {"timestamp":"2023-09-11T09:58:02.903+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported

The controller that does work is as simple as:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/")
ResponseEntity<Pit> newPIT(@RequestBody PitDto pitDto) {
    Pit createdPit = pitMapper.toEntity(pitDto);
     // some service layer stuff
    Pit savedPit = pitService.savePIT(createdPit);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(savedPit);
}
```

I don't even set the application type in that controller (however it does use Dto).

I am out of idea's but suspect something on the entity since the test entity works in that controller.

**Update**

After creating a new branch to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example the controller worked. So I changed back to master, last commit, and began to remove the properties.

The field causing a issue is `HealthCheck` - here is that class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitalizer", "handler"})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "health_check_seq", sequenceName = "HEALTH_CHECK_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 50)
@Table(name = "health_check")
public class HealthCheck {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "health_check_seq")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "bird_id")
private Bird bird;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime catchDateTime;
```

Comment: Can you link to a repo with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I created a branch. Removed all the other classes and left the one trouble entity (relationships removed) and the controller as shown above and it works. The trouble I think is on the entity properties that have relationships....will update when I know more

Comment: You didn't post a link to your repository.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75069899/content-type-application-jsoncharset-utf-8-is-not-supported-springboot-rest

Comment: I'll try to analyze it tonight, I suspect that the error message is misleading.

Comment: I fixed it. Will post solution later but it is all to do the `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference`

Comment: Remove the `produces` and `consumes` as it doesn't do what you think it does. It is used for mapping and `application/json` != `application/json;charset=UTF8` hence it will not call this method as the content types don't match. Another, unrelated thing, don't use `@Data` and `@ToString` for entities as it will generate the wrong `equals`/`hashCode` and `toString` for use with JPA. (See https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ for more info).

Comment: @M.Deinum excellent post on your site - and nice tip on `@Data` and `ToString` - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this case was to do with related/nested entities and the annotations on them for serialization/deserialization (Jackson).

On the bird class there was:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
private List<ChickTimer> listChickTimer = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
private List<Otherclass> listOtherclass = new ArrayList<>();
```

In order to fix two properties with @JsonBackReference I named them:

```
@JsonBackReference(value = "bird-chicktimer")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
private List<ChickTimer> listChickTimer = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonBackReference(value = "bird-otherclass")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bird")
private List<Otherclass> listOtherclass = new ArrayList<>();
```

I also had a `BackReference` on the Many side on one of the classes which I changed to `@JsonManagedReference`.

The `application/json` error message was a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` because it is a A String equivalent of `APPLICATION_JSON`, according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) or if you dont want to remove it just replace it to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. Why so ? because i can see in postman you do request to controller with json object not json as string

And also be sure that you dont do request with `Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8` just do it without `utf-8`

Also update i see that you also have in one entity `mappedBy = "bird"` two time on different fields, can you change one with another name something like `mappedBy = "secondBird"`

Comment: tried both `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` - same errors and tried without

Comment: I just did an update to answer

Comment: First of all try with curl without it, to see if it work great

Comment: Never tried with `charset=UTF-8` - that the controller works with a different entity makes me suspicious of entity class

Comment: i see it on example of curl request on point 6 of `Steps Taken So Far`

Comment: i just updated answer, you have in entity 2 fields with the same mapped name in database, can you change one and set another name ?

Comment: Its to do with HealthCheck class - the error is reproduceable if I try a POST on the HealthCheck controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Bird` class doesn't have default constructor without parameters. I think Sprig has trouble deserializing your JSON to `Bird` class because of it. It is a guess, but worth trying. Add

```
public Bird() {
}
```

To your class `Bird` or just remove your constructor

```
    public Bird(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: It does, it has the  `@NoArgsConstructor`  annotation.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Well, I don't like lombok (personal bias), may be try to remove the annotation and add it manually. I would try on a side to try to deserialize the JSON into a class using ObjectMapper, to rule the problem out